Concat Multi Opps ID To One String
I'm newbie in this. I have an idea like this below:
Example: I have a list Opp With 20 Close Won of only one user, I set up a flow (schedule) to scan all of its ID then input to "Send Email"
Idea1 (Everything okay):

With this idea, I received 20 Email related to 20 Opps Close Won
Idea 2: I want receive only one email includes all Close Won Opps, I used a report URL with fv0 parameter, result as I want is https://mycompany.salesforce.com/report=usefolder&fv0=OppID1,OppID2,....,OppID20

With this idea, I used loop and assigment to concat Opp Id to one string after per loop and put this string to "Send Email" but I still received 20 Email related to 20 Opps Close Won same as Idea 1
So anyone, please help me how to do it,
Thank you and Regards!

Have you considered using Scheduled Reports instead?  Especially the notification feature.

Does the 20 closed won opportunities have to be clickable links? I am thinking of using the email body, you can include all your 20 closed won opportunity there. Like this you can send one email, but this one email will include, information (that you want to include) in the email body.

The reason your first example gets 20 emails is because there are 20 interviews. Use a schedule-triggered flow on User, then there will be only 1 interview per user. Within the interview, query for the closed won oppos owned by that user and construct an email with the results
